# Unable to play some multimedia

Tags: audio, video

I have a P30 lite. When trying to play a video from YouTube (app and web), the video open, but just keeps spinning, and eventually it just freezes. I've tried both with a without WiFi.

I am unable to play videos saved on my device, and neither am I able to play videos sent to me on whatapp, nor audio clips. I am able to play voice notes though.

I've restarted my device, and I've tried logging out of YouTube, reinstalling YouTube as well as trying to use an incognito tab in chrome.

Bar reinstalling my phone, what can I attempt to fix this?

Comment: apps depend on google play services. google releases broken updates sometimes. wait for the next release

Answer (score 0):

After two days, the media started working again. It's very possibly that (as @alecxs said), there was an update done in the background that broke something, and then another one that fixed it.

Unfortunately I am unable to give a concrete solution as to how to fix this issue if this happens with anyone else.